# How can i create a file properly concatenating with literals?

Tags: javascript, csv

How can i make the same result of this

```
word +"," + num + "," +  allowed +  "," + "out.csv" +   "\n";
```

with that i am building a csv file

but i dont want to concatenate like my code above

i want to use literals

this is my attempt but does not worked

```
`${word, num, allowed, "out.csv" +"\n"}`;
```

Comment: use `${variableName}` for variables. something like ``${word},${num},${allowed},out.csv\n``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a template string, each JS expression should be wrapped in its own set of braces `${}` and anything outside the braces is treated as literal characters in the string, like so:

```
`${word},${num},${allowed},out.csv\n`;
```